# Ggplot2 - Map polygons aes fill in ggplot() versus geom()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am practicing the ggplot2 grammar of graphics on World maps using the base R dataset and the ggplot2 and mapproj packages.
When building a map that colours countries by a random variable (called "CountryColour" in the following example):

```
world_map <- map_data("world")
country_colours <- data.frame(region = c(names(table(world_map$region))),
      colour= sample(c(1:20), length(names(table(world_map$region))), replace = TRUE))
world_map <- merge(world_map, country_colours)
world_map <- world_map[order(world_map$region, world_map$order),]
```

I happened to include the aes(fill) argument in the ggplot component:

```
ggplot(world_map[abs(world_map$long) < 180,], aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=colour)) + 
    geom_polygon(color="black") +
    coord_map(projection = "mercator")
```

[image: Output Map 1]

Now, if I include it in the ggplot() component itself I get EXACTLY the same output:

```
ggplot(world_map[abs(world_map$long) < 180,], aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) +
    geom_polygon(aes(fill=colour), color="black") +
    coord_map(projection = "mercator")
```

[image: Output Map 2]

I would like to understand the conceptual difference between placing the fill function in one place or the other.

Comment: check your code.. both are the same.

Comment: In case of your plot it doesn't matter as there is only one geom layer. Generally speaking inside `ggplot` you make asthetics global, i.e. each geom will inherit these global aes. In contrast, setting an aes inside `geom` you make the aes local, i.e. other geoms will not make use of this aes.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks @stefan for clarifying.